# Use WebGoat on Windows 8

Tags: windows, java

I need to use [webgoat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Webgoat), but I can't install it on my Windows 8 computer. Do you know how to proceed ?

Comment: no i would like to know how to install it

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't an InfoSec question. This is a program installation question and better suited for SuperUser.se

Comment: ok sorry i will post the question there !

Comment: @user2505650 Please don't cross-post. This question can be migrated. Also, you'll need to provide more detail. Like what you've done already, what errors have been encountered, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You'd do better with WebGoat PHP with a basic WAMP installation or XAMPP Installation. Refer: https://github.com/shivamdixit/WebGoatPHP